# Mapstruct Error : no property named exists in source parameter(s)

Tags: java, maven, lombok, mapstruct

Hi I am trying to map my source to target but i am getting this error.

Here is My Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.26</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.0</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My Mapper:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CustomMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "rDAccount", target = "xfaceRDAccount")
    TargetClass mapToTarget(SourceClass sourceClass);
}
```

My SourceClass

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SourceClass {
    private String rDAccount;
}
```

My TargetClass

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class TargetClass {
    private String xfaceRDAccount;
}
```

After running mvn clean install
Error I am getting: No property named "rDAccount" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "RDAccount"?

Comment: Have you tried using `RDAccount`? is rDAccount simply a typo of yours?

Answer (score 2):

In the mapper calls instead of `@Mapping(source = "rDAccount", target = "xfaceRDAccount")` try using `@Mapping(source = "RDAccount", target = "xfaceRDAccount")`

The getters and setters generated by lombok for rDAccount seems to getRDAccount and setRDAccount.

[image: Generated getter and setter]

Answer (score 1):

Usually accessor for properties is generated using first character property name uppercase so `rDAccount` is interpreted from `MapStruct` (and from Lombok too, I Suppose) as `RDAccount`.
Just rename `rDAccount` as `RDAccount` and all should be fine.

Comment: yw. please accept answer if solved the problem to let other peoples have notice about solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct approach to use the `mapping` would be the following

```
@Mapping(source = "sourceClass.rDAccount", target = "xfaceRDAccount")
TargetClass mapToTarget(SourceClass sourceClass);
```